# Convenient way of checking is Shizuku server is running?

Tags: adb, tasker, termux, shizuku

How can you check if Shizuku is running before executing the start command?

I am running Shizuku on non rooted device and I noticed it randomly stops sometimes when wireless debugging becomes disabled (and this is expected AFAIK). I already have a task in  Tasker that starts Shizuku, but I want it to run only when the server is not running already otherwise I could let it simply run all day but didn't want to stick to that route.

Some users were suggesting using Termux:Tasker plugin and some adb commands to check for the `%result` but the plugin doesn't work on my device so am stuck.